# iphone pass values to the superclass from the subclass

Tags: iphone, parameter-passing, superclass

Hi, I want to pass a string value to the superclass from the subclass without using object. Can anyone please help. I know it has something to do with `[self superView]`. please help

```
class c1
{
   string s1
  -(void) m1
   {
   }
}

class c2
{
    // Here I want to call m1 and also pass values to s1 
    // without creating an object of the class c1 
}
```

Comment: You need to give some example code of what you're trying to do - your question doesn't make much sense - what do you mean 'without using an object' - an NSString __is__ an object!

Comment: Yes I hope now the question is clear

Answer (score 0):

They keyword to communicate with the superclass is `super`. You can invoke methods on the superclass like this:

```
[super myMethod:someParameter];
```

Comment: can we access the values of the super class? which are defined in the .h file

Comment: @rakendu: It should work when you use ObjC. If you use another language like eg. C++, then it will not work. But your questions wasn't really clear (your class code looks like C++ but the function looks half like ObjC)

Comment: It is in objective C. I need it in my iphone project. I need to pass a parameter to the superclass without creating an object of the superclass. PLease help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be more specific with your question.

If you're using Objective-C (the typical programming language for iPhone apps), then you can use:

```
[super superClassMethod];
```

This call takes the keyword *super*, which is a reference to the superclass, followed by the name of the message (an Objective-C method) you want to send to the superclass (Objective-C's way of "calling a method").

If you're using C++ (which your sample code seems to indicate), then I don't think you can call the superclass methods due to multiple inheritance issues.